# How to set java buildPath in command line?

Tags: java, compiler-errors, buildpath

I have two folders A and B, I want to compile java code in folder A, but the class in A need to use the class in B, so when I use javac to compile java file in A, it will show: "error: cannot find symbol".  In eclipse, I can just set the buildpath to solve this problem (add B to buildpath), but how can I set the buildPath in command line?

Answer (score 0):

try to use this command:

`javac A/*.java B/*.java`

Help it helps.

P.S.: You can use the relative ou full path of java classes.